# Помогите оптимизировать код и сделать его короче

Tags: javascript, оптимизация

Как можно вот это вот сократить?
И заменить эту строку (которая я знаю не работает):
document.getElementById('2btn', '3btn', '4btn', '5btn', '6btn').classList.remove('disabled');

JS:

```
<script>
    document.getElementById('1btn').onclick = function() {
        document.getElementById('1btn').classList.add('disabled');
        document.getElementById('2btn', '3btn', '4btn', '5btn', '6btn').classList.remove('disabled');
        document.getElementById('monoprice').innerHTML = '300 €';
        document.getElementById('biloprice').innerHTML = '350 €';
        document.getElementById('trilo1price').innerHTML = '400 €';
        document.getElementById('trilo2price').innerHTML = '440 €';
        document.getElementById('petrprice').innerHTML = '640 €';
        document.getElementById('marinaprice').innerHTML = '1000 €';
    }
    document.getElementById('2btn').onclick = function() {
        document.getElementById('2btn').classList.add('disabled');
        document.getElementById('1btn', '3btn', '4btn', '5btn', '6btn').classList.remove('disabled');
        document.getElementById('monoprice').innerHTML = '350 €';
        document.getElementById('biloprice').innerHTML = '400 €';
        document.getElementById('trilo1price').innerHTML = '500 €';
        document.getElementById('trilo2price').innerHTML = '560 €';
        document.getElementById('petrprice').innerHTML = '850 €';
        document.getElementById('marinaprice').innerHTML = '1300 €';
    }
    document.getElementById('3btn').onclick = function() {
        document.getElementById('3btn').classList.add('disabled');
        document.getElementById('1btn', '2btn', '4btn', '5btn', '6btn').classList.remove('disabled');
        document.getElementById('monoprice').innerHTML = '500 €';
        document.getElementById('biloprice').innerHTML = '650 €';
        document.getElementById('trilo1price').innerHTML = '800 €';
        document.getElementById('trilo2price').innerHTML = '950 €';
        document.getElementById('petrprice').innerHTML = '1300 €';
        document.getElementById('marinaprice').innerHTML = '1700 €';
    }
    document.getElementById('4btn').onclick = function() {
        document.getElementById('4btn').classList.add('disabled');
        document.getElementById('1btn', '2btn', '3btn', '5btn', '6btn').classList.remove('disabled');
        document.getElementById('monoprice').innerHTML = '700 €';
        document.getElementById('biloprice').innerHTML = '900 €';
        document.getElementById('trilo1price').innerHTML = '1050 €';
        document.getElementById('trilo2price').innerHTML = '1250 €';
        document.getElementById('petrprice').innerHTML = '1900 €';
        document.getElementById('marinaprice').innerHTML = '2250 €';
    }
    document.getElementById('5btn').onclick = function() {
        document.getElementById('5btn').classList.add('disabled');
        document.getElementById('1btn', '2btn', '3btn', '4btn', '6btn').classList.remove('disabled');
        document.getElementById('monoprice').innerHTML = '900 €';
        document.getElementById('biloprice').innerHTML = '1100 €';
        document.getElementById('trilo1price').innerHTML = '1300 €';
        document.getElementById('trilo2price').innerHTML = '1500 €';
        document.getElementById('petrprice').innerHTML = '2200 €';
        document.getElementById('marinaprice').innerHTML = '2700 €';
    }
    document.getElementById('6btn').onclick = function() {
        document.getElementById('6btn').classList.add('disabled');
        document.getElementById('1btn', '2btn', '3btn', '4btn', '5btn').classList.remove('disabled');
        document.getElementById('monoprice').innerHTML = '1100 €';
        document.getElementById('biloprice').innerHTML = '1300 €';
        document.getElementById('trilo1price').innerHTML = '1500 €';
        document.getElementById('trilo2price').innerHTML = '1800 €';
        document.getElementById('petrprice').innerHTML = '2400 €';
        document.getElementById('marinaprice').innerHTML = '3000 €';
    }
</script>
```

HTML:

```
<div class="choosedt">
            <p>
                <span>Выбрать дату заезда:</span>
                <button class="btn btn-mini" id="1btn">22.09 - 25.05</button>
                <button class="btn btn-mini" id="2btn">25.05 - 15.06<br>07.09 - 21.09</button>
                <button class="btn btn-mini" id="3btn">15.06 - 06.07<br>31.08 - 07.09</button>
                <button class="btn btn-mini" id="4btn">06.07 - 27.07<br>24.08 - 31.08</button>
                <button class="btn btn-mini" id="5btn">27.07 - 10.08<br>17.08 - 24.08</button>
                <button class="btn btn-mini" id="6btn">10.08 - 17.08</button>
            </p>
        </div>
```

Comment: html код в студию

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В коде повторяются идентичные части, поэтому можно вынести это в отдельную функцию. `classList` — одно с нововведений `html5`, которое, соответственно, работает не во всех браузерах. Чтобы заменить использование этого метода, стоит либо написать функцию добавления/удаления класса (учитывая возможное наличие других классов), либо же использовать атрибуты (как и сделал я).

```
function processClick(e,v){
    var i,id=['monoprice','biloprice','trilo1price','trilo2price','petrprice','marinaprice'];
    for(i=1;i<=6;i++)
        document.getElementById(i+'btn').removeAttribute('disabled');
    e.disabled='disabled';
    for(i=0;i<id.length;i++)
        document.getElementById(id[i]).innerHTML=v[i]+' €';
}
document.getElementById('1btn').onclick = function() {
    processClick(this,[300,350,400,440,640,1000]);
}
document.getElementById('2btn').onclick = function() {
    processClick(this,[350,400,500,560,850,1300]);
}
document.getElementById('3btn').onclick = function() {
    processClick(this,[500,650,800,950,1300,1700]);
}
document.getElementById('4btn').onclick = function() {
    processClick(this,[700,900,1050,1250,1900,2250]);
}
document.getElementById('5btn').onclick = function() {
    processClick(this,[900,1100,1300,1500,2200,2700]);
}
document.getElementById('6btn').onclick = function() {
    processClick(this,[1100,1300,1500,1800,2400,3000]);
}
```

Или даже так:

```
var prices=[
    [300,350,400,440,640,1000],
    [350,400,500,560,850,1300],
    [500,650,800,950,1300,1700],
    [700,900,1050,1250,1900,2250],
    [900,1100,1300,1500,2200,2700],
    [1100,1300,1500,1800,2400,3000]
],i;
for(i=0;i<prices.length;i++)
    document.getElementById((i+1)+'btn').onclick=function(){
        var j,id=['monoprice','biloprice','trilo1price','trilo2price','petrprice','marinaprice'];
        for(j=1;j<=6;j++)
            document.getElementById(j+'btn').removeAttribute('disabled');
        this.disabled='disabled';
        for(j=0;j<id.length;j++)
            document.getElementById(id[j]).innerHTML=prices[i][j]+' €';
    }
```

Так же цены, которые присваиваются при нажатии на кнопку, можно занести в какой-то из `data-*` атрибутов и брать данные оттуда — будет ещё короче.